# Return the height of a binary search tree

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I have two classes, BSTSet and BSTNode, which both have a height() method that returns the height. I'm getting a stackoverflow error and unsure as to what is causing it.

BSTSet

```
public class BSTSet <E extends Comparable<E>> extends AbstractSet <E> {

    // the root of the supporting binary search tree
    private BSTNode<E> root;

    // number of elements in the set
    private int count = 0;

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return count == 0;
    }

    public int size() {
        return count;
    }


    public int height() {
        if(root == null) return -1;
        else return root.height();
    }
}
```

BSTNode

```
public class BSTNode <E extends Comparable<E>> {

    private E value;
    private BSTNode<E> left;
    public BSTNode<E> right;

    public BSTNode(E value) {
       this.value = value;
    }

    public E getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public BSTNode<E> getLeft() {
        return left;
    }

    public BSTNode<E> getRight() {
        return right;
    }

    public int height() {
        if(left == null && right == null) return 0;
        if(left != null  && right == null) {UI.println("left");return left.height()+ 1; }
        else if(right != null && left == null){UI.println("right");return right.height()+ 1;}
        else{UI.println("both"); return Math.max(right.height(), left.height()) + 1;}
    }
}
```

If you would like anymore code or need anymore information please feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your recursive `height()` method is calling `height()` on `this`.  That is not how the algorithm ought to work, and it is the obvious cause of the infinite recursion loop that gives you the stack overflow.

@xgeorgekx's approach should give the right answer, but I'm not convinced that it is optimal.  If the tree is balanced, then the heights of the left and right subtrees are related ... and you *may* not need to traverse both sides.  If you can avoid that, then the `height` method can be implemented as `O(logN)` not `O(N)`.

I suspect that your original approach is trying to be `O(logN)` ...

Comment: Of course that makes sense. Yes trying to be O(logN). I'm still slightly confused as to what the optimal solution should be though, sorry still learning

Comment: I'm not sure myself ... which is why my answer is "vague" on that point :-).  The optimal solution depends on the precise invariants of the balanced tree that you are implementing.

Comment: I have managed to get the code working somewhat but the problem I come across is when the is both a left and right node... check my edit for BSTNode

Comment: That may be the best solution.  I don't know.  As I said, it depends on the tree invariants; e.g. if you *know* that the left subtree is always taller or always shorter than the right subtree.  The other thing to note is that some balanced tree algorithms store the height (or "weight") of the current node in the node itself, and update it incrementally.  In fact, this may be necessary if you need that value for rebalancing.  (Otherwise rebalancing could be very expensive ... in the worst case.)

Answer (score 0):

`if(left == null && right == null) return 0;`

change to

`if(left == null && right == null) return 1;`

If a node has no children it still has height of `1`

Then just make a recursive call like this 
`else return Max(left.height(), right.tHeight) + 1;`

By definition the height of a node is the maximum height of it's sub-tress + 1

The stack overflow is due to calling the `height()` method on the same node here:

```
else if(left != null && right == null || left == null && right != null) return height()+ 1;
else return height()+ 2;
```

I just wanna throw this in. If you want a single node, to start at height `0` obviously keep the 
`if(left == null && right == null) return 0;`

Comment: Unfortunately the I'm unable to use max but I edited my code to get it working but I believe its not returning the correct value...